# Use static library in Swift framework

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, sdwebimage

I have a project that is mainly Objective-C. However, it is using frameworks designed by another team using Swift. Both teams are using the SDWebImage Cocoapod.

We get the 'module missing' error when compiling the project. Turning on 'use_frameworks!' for the framework projects would work, but Cocoapods does not allow child projects to have that on without the master project having it — which we cannot do.

What is the best way to include a static library built as a Cocoapod into a Swift project without using the `use_frameworks!` directive in the `Podfile`?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?